# Parse from string

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have an awful looking string like this:

```
"[{ \"value\" \\: \"hello\"}]"
```

If I wanted to parse "hello" from this, how would I do it? Considering the format of the string will always remain the same but the word "hello" will change, I need a somewhat robust method that can find the "hello" based on it's surroundings. Should I use regex, or is there a better way? I can use substring to find the start of "hello", maybe thats the best way to do it?

Many thanks

Comment: If it weren't for the \\ in your string, I'd suggest using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: True, but I could remove the \\.. hmmmm

Comment: replace \ with "" no? I mean, better to replace it with nothing before json.parse?

Comment: JSON.parse(string.replace('\', ''));

Comment: Probably better to tackle this problem at the source; who is giving you malformed JSON and can you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse("[{ \"value\" \\: \"hello\"}]".replace(/\\/g,''))[0].value
```